# VB Import variable then use part 1 in dropdown and display part 2 to match selection in part 1

Tags: vb.net

I'm using Visual studio to build a small utility.

I'm importing variables from a text file (this makes my program expandable in the future).

I'm running into a road block trying to split the variables into usable parts.

The text file is set up as such:

```
Game1:flshflhdlsfsdsfs
Game2:ugdjgndrgbdvdnjd
Game3:gnnereknengievke
```

And the code I've gathered from searching around trying to understand how I could do this is (It's gone through multiple rewrites but I feel this is probably the closest I've gotten):

```
    Dim value As String = File.ReadAllText("Games.txt")
    Dim cut_at As String = ":"
    Dim x As Integer = InStr(value, cut_at)

    Dim string_before As String = value.Substring(0, x - 2)
    Dim string_after As String = value.Substring(x + cut_at.Length - 1)

    Games_drp.Items.AddRange(string_before)
```

When I run a test like this, I get an error that String_before cannot be converted to an object. I tried switching "Dim string_before As String = value.Substring(0, x - 2)" to Dim string_before As Object = value.Substring(0, x - 2), but the dropdown that's supposed to be populated by at least one of the entries before the : has absolutely nothing in it.

Being pretty new at VB and feeling like I've exhausted pretty much every way I could think of searching in google and trying to piece together various bits of information, I figure I'd try asking my own direct question:

How would I go about reading all the lines from a text file, then splitting before the : to fill a combobox, and using a label to display the string after the : matching which ever entry is selected in the dropdown.

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

**EDIT with full code:**

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Saves_frm
    Private Sub Saves_frm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim value As String = File.ReadAllText("Games.txt")
        Dim cut_at As String = ":"
        Dim x As Integer = InStr(value, cut_at)

        Dim string_before As String = value.Substring(0, x - 2)
        Dim string_after As String = value.Substring(x + cut_at.Length - 1)

        Games_drp.Items.AddRange(string_before)

    End Sub
End Class
```

When run as is, I get an error that 'string_before' can't be converted from a string to an object, but when I make the following change from:

Dim string_before As String = value.Substring(0, x - 2)

to:

Dim string_before As Object = value.Substring(0, x - 2)

The error goes away, but the dropdown remains blank.

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines` might give you a better starting point.  Rather than parsing the strings. you could save the data in parts as in a csv

Comment: ...or you could use `String.Split(":")` to split a String into an array of the different parts.

Comment: Probably want to show us more of your code and explain the error you're having.

Comment: @clweeks

This is pretty much all the code I have other than it's in a private sub. I'll edit the question to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to use File.ReadAllLines, as it returns an array with all the file's lines.  Then, you can loop through the lines, splitting each line and adding the result to the ListBox. This should be an example, but feel free to correct any mistakes I made, as I wrote it on my phone and it's been a long time since I used VB.

```
Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt")

For Each line As String In lines
  Dim split() As String = line.Split(":"c)
  gDic.Add(split(0), split(1))
Next
```

EDIT: Then, you most certainly want a dictionary that contains the name and the data, check the updated code.
Then, add the names by looping through gDic.Keys. When a name is selected, access its value with gDic("key").

Comment: This works, but only partially. I'm not sure about how I would go about matching the string selected in the dropdown and displaying the second part in a label, which is the part that's really been the head-scratcher for me.

Comment: Thanks for the step in the right direction. Still a few things to work out, but I'll figure it out.